# Visual Studio Bundler & Minifier Context Menu Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I've installed Bundler & Minifier v 2.4.337 to my website project in Visual Studio 2015.  But, when I right-click a *.js file the context menu option to Minify File is not present.  I've used B&M before in other projects successfully.  Something about this version just isn't working for me.  Any ideas how to get the context menu options to appear?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue with visual studio 2017, fixed it by going to Tools --> Extensions and updates. On installed tab, look for Bundler and Minifier extension and enable it. For some reason it was disabled after installing the IDE and Web essentials.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Even though the package was installed it didn't show it in the options. So, I bundled the files using CLI. Follow following steps:
1. Goto your project in command prompt.
2. Run following commands in order:

```
dotnet add package BuildBundlerMinifier
dotnet restore
dotnet build
dotnet clean
```

Note that dotnet restore command is only required if you're using ASP.NET Core 1.x. 
Executing these commands will bundle and minify the files.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR.**

In fact, it works normally, but when it encounters critical errors in js or css files, its code breaks and the errors prevent the `.min` file. Therefore, you should close js or css filenames in `bundleconfig.json` file one by one as comments (`//`) until Bundle and Minifier works as intented.

---

**Long Explanation**

I was facing that problem years later. I noticed that Bundler and Minifier are working as designed. However, the minified file cannot be created if the base css or js file has too many critical errors.

[image: JS errors]

[image: Bundler & Minifier errors]

We are closing the reported as have critical errors by Bundle&Minifier step by step.

[image: JS files]]

And bingo! The minify file is created.

[image: Bundle updated]]

In conclusion, you should find the problem file and try to minify after remove it. I mean, you should fix the errors or remove the filename in `bundleconfig.json` if you want the append the problem file to the minify file. If there are not a lot of errors, I fix them, or if there are too many errors in the file, I'm re-adding them manually after Bundle&Minifier has created.

For example, I use [ckeditor5](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5) in my project and its own [minify CDN file](https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/29.1.0/classic/ckeditor.js) is about 750 KB, its size is about 2 mb as unminify. After many attemps I realized that it couldn't be minified because even its built code was full of errors(approx. 200 errors)

By the way, I realized this case after using [jscompress](https://jscompress.com) website. You can check that and you will see the errors. Then you will see the errors with VS Code after as unminify.

Answer (score -1):

Go to Tools->Task Runner Explorer on main menu. Rigth click Update all files under bundleconfig.json and click Bindings-> Project Open

So, all files you have selected for minifing will be automatically created and recreated whenever they saved.

For more info visit: http://rion.io/2016/07/18/bundling-and-minifying-in-asp-net-core-applications/