# .NET Core2.0 bundleconfig.json not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bundle

I'm struggling trying to get bundling to work in a Core 2.0 web application.  I have the following in my **bundleconfig.json** file:

```
[
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/site.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/jquery-datatables.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/datatables.css",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/Responsive-2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.css"
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/site.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/js/site.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/jquery.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/js/jquery-datatables.min.js",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/datatables.js",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/Responsive-2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.js"
    ],
    "minify": {
      "enabled": true,
      "renameLocals": true
    },
    "sourceMap": false
  }
]
```

I installed the BuildBundlerMinifier NugGet package. When I build the project i see the bundleconfig.json file being processed.
I added the following to **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />                        
    <environment include="Development,Staging,Production">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/wwwroot/css/site.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/wwwroot/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/wwwroot/css/jquery-datatables.min.css" />            
    </environment>
</head>
<body>
    <environment include="Development,Staging,Production">
        <script src="~/wwwroot/js/site.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/wwwroot/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/wwwroot/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/wwwroot/js/jquery-datatables.min.js"></script>            
    </environment>
    @RenderSection("Scripts", required: true)
</body>
```

When I run the application the resources aren't loaded. I'm getting the following errors:

> Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “https://localhost:44301/wwwroot/js/site.min.js”.
>   Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “https://localhost:44301/wwwroot/js/jquery.min.js”.
>   Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “https://localhost:44301/wwwroot/js/bootstrap.min.js”.
>   Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “https://localhost:44301/wwwroot/js/jquery-datatables.min.js”

Can someone please help me?

Comment: From where did you get this `BuildBundlerMinifier` package? The default file works directly with the Web Essentials 2017 extension

Comment: i got the idea for BuildBundlerMinifier here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x

Comment: I have had stated the exact solution in my [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68665120/13664939) answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remove the *"wwwroot"* part in the urls. *"wwwroot"* is the root folder where your application is running. Now it will search the files in *"...wwwroot/wwwroot/js..."* instead of *"...wwwroot/js..."*.

Comment: None of these solutions works at all I get no output generated

This is complete and utter rubbish. Why does Microsoft do such things to screw you over just when something is going well?

Comment: The paths of the files in the bundleconfig.json are relative the config file. So if the bundleconfig.json is at the same level as wwwroot, we need to add wwwroot to the file path. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?tabs=visual-studio,aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 18):

I tired it  for Nuget Package Manager but it didn't work, then uninstall that ,

**Solved** with:

open **Nuget Package Manager console**,

```
Install-Package BuildBundlerMinifier -Version 2.8.391
```

and **Rebuild solution** again. it works for me.

Comment: I had this installed/working fine using Nuget manager, but then the next day it would no longer update the bundled file.  I did a Rebuild on the solution level as you mention, and that kicked into working on regular project build again.

Answer (score 12):

I could not get this working and learned that there is more to the problem at the present time.

By default none of the Bundling & Minifying stuff is installed in a dotnet core razor pages project.

Supposedly, you can can check your settings by right-clicking the **bundleconfig.json** in Visual Studio Solution Explorer.  But that doesn't show anything in my project.

I finally found a **Visual Studio Add-in**.

**Bundler & Minifier -- manual**

Instead I installed a manual bundler & minifier -- which is written by the same author (Mads Kristensen) as the Nuget pkg from above.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier

That's a Visual Studio extension and after you install it, you can right-click any css or js file and you'll get menu which allows you to minify them "manually".
[image: bundle file]

**Enable bundle on build...**

That option will warn you that it is going to install a Nuget package.  I didn't do that yet.

I also unchecked that option [Produce Output Files] and then selected it again (checked) and when I did that another file was created in my solution underneath the **bundleconfig.json** named **bundleconfig.json.bindings**.  That file contains just one line:

```
produceoutput=true
```

It's odd that it wasn't there previously.  I know that file didn't exist previously, because git told me there are untracked files and mentioned that file.

To test if there is a problem in studio or something, I created a brand new dotnet Core 2.x Razor Pages project, then immediately deleted the min.css and tried to build it again but it woudln't ever build again.

Update All Bundles
I built again after the .bindings file was added, but the bundles still weren't built.
I then noticed that I have another option under the [Build] menu but I'm not sure if that is the Bundling & Minifying plugin I installed so you'll have to consider that when looking for this solution.

[image: update all bundles]

You can also check your settings in the Visual Studio [Tools...Options...] menu:

[image: Tools and Options]
You can see that the Bundler & Minifier has the Product Output files option set to true in my project (even though it still isn't working).

Actually, I read that bottom sentence a little more closely and I noticed that it says, "actively listens to input file changes" so I went and changed my site.css and noticed that the value was indeed updated in the site.css.

**Make A Change, Change It Back**

The odd thing is when / if you delete your site.min.css then it doesn't seem to get regenerated at any time.  I guess now if you do that, you could make a change and change it back and the min file would be created.

I tested that: deleted site.min.css then made a change and the file was gen'd again.  It's just odd that the build doesn't fire this functionality.

Comment: this was helpful and I did lil modification to get it working. Posted as an answer below

Answer (score 6):

As per documentation from Microsoft [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-2.0&tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x#build-time-execution-of-bundling-and-minification)

> The [BuildBundlerMinifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/) NuGet package enables the execution of bundling and minification at build time.

This got me annoyed at first too because it isn't installed by default and the implication of the bundler seems to be that it should just work built-in. But that is not the case.

Comment: Thats because: The Bundler & Minifier extension belongs to a community-driven project on GitHub for which Microsoft provides no support. Your answer is not a Microsoft developed solution.

Comment: The owner (and author) of the package works for Microsoft.  He worked for Microsoft when he wrote it.  They've documented it on their docs pages.  This isn't the only project that's in some kind of limbo 'almost Microsoft' status.  My guess is you're right that this is so they don't have to support it.

Answer (score 5):

The ultimate solution that I did is 
Removed - `<PackageReference Include="BundlerMinifier.Core" Version="2.8.391" />`
Added  - `<PackageReference Include="BuildBundlerMinifier" Version="2.9.406" />` to get it working.

Adding VS extension and enabling the bundle on build step also adds the BuildBundlerMinifier package.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not using wwwroot in your path. The problem is that you are using the ~ notation before wwwroot, and that tells the browser to use the root path (wwwroot) and the what follows your path, which is also wwwroot.

You can use the absolute path

```
"inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/css/site.css"
    ]
```

Or the relative path

```
 "inputFiles": 
      "~/css/site.css"
    ]
```

Both not the too at the same time, because **the relative path complement the full path with the ~ or ../ notation**.

Another observation on your scripts. Why the heck do you keep the files apart?
The purpose of the bundle is that you don't have to include each separate file. It combines them in one minified file and make less request to the server to load the pages. Don't keep the datatables scripts separate from your scripts.

Instead of:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    ]
  },
  {
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/jquery-datatables.min.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/datatables.css",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/Responsive-2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.css"
    ]
  },
```

Your should put:

```
{
    "outputFileName": "wwwroot/css/myStyles.css",
    "inputFiles": [
      "wwwroot/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/datatables.css",
      "wwwroot/lib/jquery/jquery-datatables/Responsive-2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.css"
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Did install the BuildBundlerMinifier.Core version (3.0.415). That did not work, however the not core version of BuildBundlerMinifier (3.0.415) works fine (in a asp.net core 2.2 project).

Comment: weird but also uninstalling the core version and installing the regular version worked!

Answer (score 2):

Install **BuildBundlerMinifier** and it will help to create min files

Comment: Here's what I was missing!

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue today. The key for me was that the nuget package ([BuildBundlerMinifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier/)) wasn't enough for this to work. You need to also install the [Bundler and Minifier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BundlerMinifier) VS extension. From there, you can follow the [instructions here](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier#bundle-on-build--ci-support) to enable bundling on build. Note that the VS extension will also install the nuget package if you do not already have it.

Regarding why this doesn't work out of the box, I believe it is because this is a fairly new 3rd-party tool produced by Mads.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer given by raddevus above; open the Task Explorer in Visual Studio, expand bundleconfig.json; right click on **Update all files** and select **Binding** then **After build** ... tad-dah!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After install VS 2017 Community 2017, version 15.8.9

Bundling & Minifying stop working

Installing in NuGet don't work

So, in Tools menu, Extensions and Updates, after updating Bundling & Minifying, and restarting VS, its go to work

Now, after select bundleconfig.json , right-clicking, in popup menu, its show the item "Bundler & Minified"

Comment: Installing madskristensen/WebEssentials2017 together can disable "Bundling & Minifying" , both from same author, it looks like it has been installed 2 times